# How to make nginx access symbolic path without permission issue

Tags: symlink, nginx

I created a symbolic link path in nginx server side which reference to my documents directory

```
[user1@localhost nginx] pwd 
/user/share/nginx

[user1@localhost nginx] sudo ln -s ~/Documents/nginx-sites/app app
[user1@localhost nginx] ls
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   37 Sep 21 14:58 app -> /home/user1/Documents/nginx-sites/app
```

However, nginx user seem like unable to access that files (permission denied)

> *nginx error log here* -> 2022/09/21 13:35:20 [error] 20547#20547: *3 open() "/usr/share/nginx/app/public" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /app/public HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"

So i try to perform **stat** command by using **http (my nignx user)** to try out access the directory, here's the outcome.

```
// 1'st tried

[user1@localhost nginx]$ sudo -u http stat app/public
stat: cannot statx 'app/public': Permission denied
```

```
// 2nd tried -> cd inside subsequently, and perform stat again

[user1@localhost nginx]$ sudo -u http stat app
 File: app -> /home/user1/Documents/nginx-sites/app
  Size: 37              Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   symbolic link
Device: 259,2   Inode: 13375664    Links: 1
...

[user1@localhost nginx]$ cd app
[user1@localhost app]$ sudo -u http stat public
File: public
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 259,2   Inode: 11015535    Links: 2
...
```

As the results, 1st tried failed, but 2nd success. Why this behavior occur?
How can i make following works?

1. nginx user can access and serve them.
2. sudo -u http stat app/public return success.

```
/*For information purpose*/

[user1@localhost ~]$ groups http
user1 http

[user1@localhost ~]$ ls ~/Documents/nginx-sites
drwxr-xr-x 13 user1 user1 4096 Sep 21 14:16 app

[user1@localhost ~]$ ls ~/Documents/nginx-sites/app
drwxr-xr-x  7 user1 user1   4096 Sep 20 21:19 app
-rwxr-xr-x  1 user1 user1   1686 Sep 20 21:19 artisan
drwxr-xr-x  3 user1 user1   4096 Sep 20 21:19 bootstrap
drwxr-xr-x  2 user1 user1   4096 Sep 20 21:19 public
```